# How to make a list of image links in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, download, hyperlink

I have a list of links. What I want to do is attach a function to each link with jQuery; when the link is clicked, the function will run, and a pair of images will be loaded into a div (img ids "img1" and "img2"). Each link has the class "link", and will load a different pair of images. So, the first link will load Image 1A and Image 1B, the second will load Image 2A and 2B, and so on. I have the images in two arrays.

However, instead of attaching the calls like I want, it ends up loading the last two images of the arrays, after the page stops loading. What's more, clicking on the links does nothing!

```
var loadImages =
{
    init: function()
    {
        var links = $( ".link" );
        myArray1 = [ 
            "imgs/png/image1.png",
            "imgs/png/image2.png",
            "imgs/png/image3.png",
        ];
        myArray2 = [ 
            "imgs/jpg/image1.jpg",
            "imgs/jpg/image2.jpg",
            "imgs/jpg/image3.jpg",
        ];
        for ( var i = 0, ii = links.length; i < ii; i++ )
        {
            $( links[ i ] ).bind( "click", loadImages.imgLoader( myArray1[ i ],
                myArray2[ i ] ) );
        }
    },
    imgLoader: function( firstURI, secondURI )
    {
        document.getElementById( "img1" ).src = firstURI;
        document.getElementById( "img2" ).src = secondURI;
    }
};
loadImages.init();
```

Comment: You have a comma at the end of your last item in each array...That's not good. It may be causing your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You don't bind a callback *function*. You execute `loadImages.imgLoader` and pass the result.

Normally you could just bind a callback function, but since you're using a counter variable within the callback itself, you need to be wary of the scope of `i`:

```
$(links[i]).on("click", (function(j) {
    return function() {
        loadImages.imgLoader(myArray1[j], myArray2[j]);
    }
})(i));
```

A better approach would be to bind the event handler to all of the links at once and handle the image swapping without a `for` loop:

```
$('.link').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();

    $('#img1').prop('src', myArray1[index]);
    $('#img2').prop('src', myArray2[index]);
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I do like the second approach better, but it didn't work at first. (I had to change the second line to `var index = $( '.link' ).index( this );`.) Anyway, I think I have a lot to learn about callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the `.each()` method.

```
var loadImages = {
  init: function(){
    var myArray1 = ['imgs/png/image1.png', 'imgs/png/image2.png', 'imgs/png/image3.png'];
    var myArray2 = ['imgs/jpg/image1.jpg', 'imgs/jpg/image2.jpg','imgs/jpg/image3.jpg'];
    $('.link').each(function(i){
      $(this).click(function(){
        loadImages.imgLoader(myArray1[i], myArray2[i]);
      });
    });
  },
  imgLoader: function(firstURI, secondURI){
    $('#img1').attr('src', firstURI);
    $('#img2').attr('src', secondURI);
  }
};
loadImages.init();
```

Also, you should use the keyword `var` so your variables don't have a global scope, and remove commas at the end of your Arrays. Visit http://api.jquery.com/each/ for more information on `.each()`.

Comment: Oh, I am not familiar with `.each()`. I will check this out. Thank you.